# Antlr4 C# ommitting whitespaces with (-> skip) or WS* doesn't work

Tags: c#, antlr4, dsl

I'm improving an integration testing tool that is used for RPC calls. I'm currently able to reply to calls with simple static answers, the likes of:

`<PackageType>Success/Reply</PackageType> <Server>default</Server> <Date>13.01.2020</Date>...`

To avoid recompiling the code for different test cases, protocols and developers, I want to integrate a small DSL. It should work like in the following example:

```
<PackageType>{Random ( "Success","Error")}/Reply</PackageType><Server>{Input ("COMPUTERNAME") }</Server> <Date>{DateTime}</DateTime>
<PackageType>Error/Reply</PackageType><Server>sv_15</Server><Date>01/13/2020 16:45:23</Date>
```

For that, I developed following grammar in Antlr:

```
grammar GRAM;
expression  : expression expression                     #ExpressionWalk
            | OPENTAG instruction CLOSETAG              #GetInstruction
            | STRING                                    #StringBlock
            ;
instruction : function ( '(' param(',' param)* ')' )?   #InstructionBuilder
            ;           
function    : FUNC;                                     #FunctionCreator
param       : '"' STRING '"'                            #StringParam
            | NEGATOR? INT                              #IntParam
            ; 
STRING      : (~( OPENTAG | CLOSETAG | '"' | ',' ) )+;
INT         : [0-9]+;
NEGATOR     : '-';
OPENTAG     : '{' ;
CLOSETAG    : '}';
FUNC        : 'Random' | 'Input' | 'DateTime' ;   
WS          : [ \r\n\t] -> skip;
```

Since TestRig doesn't work with CSharp target, I'm using following code to test my grammar:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = "albalbalb{ Random ( \"string1\" , \"string2\")}blablabla ";
    ICharStream stream = CharStreams.fromstring(input);
    ITokenSource lexer = new GRAMLexer(stream);
    ITokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
    GRAMParser parser = new GRAMParser(tokens);
    parser.BuildParseTree = true;
    IParseTree tree = parser.expression();
    Console.WriteLine(tree.ToStringTree(parser));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I run the code, I'm getting the following error:

```
line 1:11 mismatched input ' Random ' expecting FUNC
line 1:19 no viable alternative at input ','
```

The whitespaces around ' Random ' tell me that somehow Antlr is unable to seperate them from the FUNC lexer. This is also true when I change (-> skip) to manually placed "WS*" instructions (I'll need that if I want to allow whitespaces in strings).

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use VS Code, Eclipse or NetBeans to test your ANTLR grammar. You could use [this VS Code  extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4) to validate your grammar.

Comment: What you posted is XML though. The kind of template you propose can easily be implemented using string interpolation (although it can produce invalid XML). Even if you want to use ANTLR for XML parsing, you can use the XML grammar examples

Comment: The *real* problem with this DSL is that you're mixing two different languages. XML and your own syntax. Instead of trying to get a single syntax to cover *both* grammars you could use modes to use the XML grammar on the outside, your own syntax when the first character in an element is your delimiter `{`

Comment: BTW XSLT is already used for this kind of transformations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your tips, but my example was highly simplified. In reality, SOAP is hidden behind an existing library and the message parameters are edited through TextFields in a GUI Client. Since many RPC calls need some level of logic (eg. increasing message id by 1 or adding hashes from input data), we could only test one package at a time before editing the data in the GUI again. I know that a DSL still isn't a perfect solution here, but the license for the original component is too expensive for a testing environment.

Comment: What's the point of this then? You can generate a proxy and classes from WSDL, no ANTLR4 or templates required. Definitely no XML generation. Besides, SOAP is **much** more than the schema - you can't implement WS-* protocols like authentication, security etc just by filling in a template. You can bind UI controls to the classes generated by WSDL. Back in the 00s some companies tried to autogenerate the UI from the XSD but the result is *really* ugly. SOAP's schema is *VERY* different from the view model of a good UI

Comment: Later on, the SharePoint team though that using XSLT and templates to generate the UI from XSD+XML data was a good idea. Everyone else still hates them for it, 13 years later. Creating the UI through transformations is a *LOT* harder than simply adding the controls plus some data binding and a lot *slower*.

Comment: And finally, users of template-generated SOAP services *hate* them. As in really, really hate them. That's because the template *always* contains an error, making it impossible to generate a proxy from WSDL. That forces everyone to hand-code XML strings once again, instead of simply sending a strongly-typed DTO to a well defined endpoint. Never mind details like security, headers. conversation IDs etc. It's *so* funny when the serives sends a 5 for an attribute whose XSD says its range is 1-3

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think we're talking at cross purposes here. WDSL compliant package generation, type checking, AAA... thats all done through the library, and we don't have UI with raw user input. The software we're testing is a highly sophisticated distributed SCADA system, and we only need this tool to emulate an otherwise very expensive supervisory systems. The SOAP part isn't important. What we want to see is if the queues distribute the packages properly, if our broadacsting works and if a change in values (eg. increasing pressure in a set of valves) properly reflect in the PI Diagrams

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with the original and modified grammars.

(1) Your original grammar does not parse. The alt labeled was placed after the semicolon, which marks the end of the rule (**"function    : FUNC; #FunctionCreator"** should be **"function    : FUNC   #FunctionCreator ;"**).

(2) If you print out the token stream from the lexer for your original grammar, you would see that the input can’t parse because it is expecting a FUNC token, but receives a STRING token instead. The token stream is “albalbalb” (STRING; match); “{“ (OPENTAG; match); “ Random (“ (STRING; expecting FUNC).

(3) While your modified grammar may work, you have the lexer recognizing every single character as a separate token. Most parsers do not do this because the point of a lexer is to group characters together into “tokens” which are then read by the parser. The lexer employs a fast machine to recognize tokens. On the other hand, the parser employs a slower augmented (or alternatively network) transition network machine.

(4) The reason why you need the CHAR rule in your modified grammar is because you have the string literals in the parser rules define most of the tokens recognized by the lexer. Rules staticstring and paramstring define only  ‘{‘, ‘}’, ‘”’. ‘(‘, ‘)’. Other string literals in the parser portion of the grammar are ‘-‘, ‘ ‘, 'Variable', etc. Recognition fails with “line 1:0 token recognition error at: 'a' “ (a lexer error) because you haven’t a string literal ‘a’ in the parser. The CHAR rule in the grammar allows the lexer to recognize all characters.

(5) I would recommend checking out some of the grammars in https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4. To write good grammars, everyone should study them.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work, so I started again from the beginning.
For the record, it seems that you have to add a Lexer rule "CHAR" that contains all possible characters so the parser "knows" them before he can remove them.

Here is what I'm doing instead:

```
grammar GRAM;
/* Each expression can be multiple functions or strings
 * Strings can contain every char except those specified under string
*/
start           : expression EOF                                            #StartRule
                ;
expression      : expression expression                                     #ExpressionWalk
                | '{' function '}'                                          #GetFunction
                | staticstring                                              #GetStaticString
                ;
/* Function always have ONE instruction and zero or more parameters
*/
function        : ' '* instruction ' '* parameters? ' '*                    #FunctionBuilder
                ;
/* Instructions are specified here so its easier to work with them in code
*/  
instruction     : 'Variable'                                                #GetVariableInstruction
                | 'DateTime'                                                #GetDateTimeInstruction
                | 'RandomInt'                                               #GetRandomIntInstruction
                | 'Random'                                                  #GetRandomInstruction
                | 'CountInt'                                                #GetCountIntInstruction
                ;
/* If parameters exist, it is always one or more parameters
*/
parameters      : '(' ' '* parameter ' '* ( ',' ' '* parameter  ' '* )+  ')' #WalkParameters
                ;
/* Two types of parameters are allowed: Strings, which must be incapsulated in ",
 * and Integers, which don't have "
 */
parameter       : '"' paramstring '"'                                       #StringParam
                | '-'? DIGIT+                                               #IntParam
                ;
/* List of disallowed characters for parameters and static text
*/
staticstring    : (~( '{' | '}' ))+                                         #OuterExclude
                ;
paramstring     : (~('"' | '(' | ')' ))+                                    #InnerExclude
                ;

/* Lexer rules. CHAR is needed to allow characters in parser system
*/                      
DIGIT           : [0-9]                 ;
CHAR            : ('\u0000'..'\uFFFF')  ;
```

I'll wait another day before accepting this myself so if someone has a better still has the chance to post it